# How to determine if a context-free grammar describes a regular language?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language, finite-automata, formal-languages

Given an arbitrary context-free grammar, how can I check whether it describes a regular language?

I'm not looking for exam "tricks". I'm looking for a foolproof mechanical test that I can code.

If it helps, here's an example of a CFG that I might receive as an input.
Specifically, notice that the answer must be much more complicated than just looking for left- or right-recursion, since the presence of another type of recursion does not automatically imply the grammar is irregular.

```
S: A B C D X
A: A a
A:
B: b B
B:
C: c C c
C: c
D: D d D
D: d
X: x Y
X:
Y: y X
Y:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such mechanical procedure because the problem of determining whether a CFG defines a regular language is undecidable.

This result is a simple application of [Greibach's Thereom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem#Applications).

Comment: That was painful to read :) I most definitely did *not* see it coming. Thanks though!

Comment: By the way, if you know whether there is a more restricted superset of regular grammars whose regularity can be determined, then that might be nice to add to the answer.